# Deadlock between 2 transactions using ROWLOCK and UPDLOCK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, deadlock

I have some Ruby on Rails code using SQLServer 2008rc2 and I'm running into a deadlock issue.
This is how my code looks like from a SQL point of view:

```
begin transaction
  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
  select * from table1 with (rowlock, updlock) where id = 1234 -- fetch the object with a lock
  -- do several queries, all with nolock or no hint
  -- this can take a few seconds
  update table1 with(rowlock) set x = 'y' where id = 1234
end
```

This happens on a web server so sometimes there are 2 transactions at the same time. The problem here is that sometimes 2 requests for 2 very different ids get deadlocked.

At first the hints weren't there and the transaction isolation wasn't set. I thought it was a pagelock creating a problem so I added ROWLOCK and READ UNCOMMITED. Then I found an issue about making updates in SHARED transactions so I used UPDLOCK. Now I'm running out of ideas.

Does that sound familiar to anybody ?

Comment: read uncommitted followed by rowlock, updlock. really?

Comment: AFAIK isolation level defines the default for the transaction and can be changed using the hints. There's like 40 requests in there where read uncommitted is the proper level.
That said, I'm way more used to postgres and all these SQLServer locks and hints are very cryptic to me.

Comment: "like 40 requests in there where read uncommitted is the proper level" - The only time I use read uncommitted is for reporting queries where absolute consistency is not paramount.

Comment: Maybe ... I'm just following the instructions of our DB admin. As I said I'm trying to understand how these things are working.

Comment: Perhaps your DBAdmin doesn't actually know what they are doing?  Just a thought....It does happen...

Comment: Obtaining an update lock on the resources regardless of what transaction isolation level you are on, will block other users's access to them resources while Update operation is being executed.

Comment: Blocking access to the resources I'm using IS what I want. My issue there is that 2 transactions for 2 different objects deadlock one another. That's not suppose to happen.

Comment: Also: You appear to be in the rather unusual situation of having a DBA. Have you talked to them?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this type of deadlock before when multiple indexes on the same table are involved. You should capture and study the deadlock graph.

To do this, set trace flag 1222 in SSMS:

dbcc traceon(1222,-1)

Then, start a SQL Profiler session and add the event called Deadlock Graph, under Locks. Be sure to select all columns for this event. What I've seen is a circular block chain where one transaction locks a key in a non-clustered index, then tries to update some field, which would necessitate an update to the clustered index, but some other transaction had a lock on the same key in the clustered index, and was then trying to lock the key in the non-clustered index that was being held by the first transaction.

Keep in mind that the rowlock hint is actually more like a suggestion, and the database engine may not respect it if it deems that locking overhead is too high, it might just escalate to locking the entire index/table as the case may be.